# ¿Cómo poner nuevamente el cursor en datepicker despues de seleccionar fecha?

Tags: javascript

tengo un problema al hacer una validación de edad cuando elijo en datepicker. Hago la validación con JavaScript de modo que salga un alert y borre el input cuando la edad sea menor que 16. Eso me sale bien si introduzco la fecha por teclado de esta forma 14/11/1992, pero cuando lo hago en el calendario que sale, me llena el campo pero no hace nada. Pienso que es porque hago la validación con blur. Este hace que se pierda el foco cuando se llena el campo pero no se pasa a otro input. Si alguien sabe porque pasa y me puede ayudar, este es el código:

```js
$('#tblprospectos-fecha_nac').datepicker({
          format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
        }).on('blur', function(){
          var dateBith = $(this).val();
              
              if (dateBith != '') {
                dateBith = moment(dateBith, "DD-MM-YYYY");
                dateBith = dateBith.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
                var years = moment().diff(dateBith, 'years');

                $('#tblprospectos-edad').val(years);

                if (years < 16) {
                  alert("Debe ser igual o mayor a 16");
                }
             }
              else{
                $('#tblprospectos-edad').val('');
              }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="hero-unit">
            Fecha de nacimiento:
            <input type="text" placeholder="Seleccione fecha de nacimiento" id="tblprospectos-fecha_nac">
        </div>
        <div class="hero-unit">
            Edad:
            <input type="text" id="tblprospectos-edad">
        </div>
        <div class="hero-unit">
            Correo:
            <input type="text" id="otro">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Según lo que dices, por que no pruebas cambiando de evento ? cambia de blur a change, el cual se ejecutará en cualquiera de las dos situaciones!

Comment: Si de hecho es lo que hice pero ahora solo me deja seleccionar del calendario del datepicker y ahora no deja introducirlo por teclado. Deben de poderse las dos formas de igual manera la condición que la edad sea mayor que 16, pero gracias por el consejo.

Comment: busca si tu datepicker tiene algun evento `close` o algo similar, y ahi has tu validacion.

Comment: Por que no tratas de crear un ejemplo completo mirando [mcve] para poder reproducirlo y mirar mejor que puede estar sucediendo

Comment: Lo trate de cambiar como pude jeje. No se como sacar el alert aqui me hice bolas. Ahora para que se den una idea, si prueban introduciendo la fecha con el teclado en este formato 15/11/1992 y le dan clic o tab hacia otro campo se supone debe calcular la edad y colocarla en el siguiente campo. La otra parte de la explicación esta en el siguiente comentario xD.

Comment: Si el calculo se da cuenta que es una edad menor que 16 debe mandar el alert y hasta aqui me sale bien probando en la pc. El problema es que si el usuario ingresa la fecha seleccionando desde el calendario, si se dan cuanta lo pone, pero no pasa al siguiente input asi que para que se active la validación tenemos que hacer clic forzosamente en el datepicker o en otro textbox. Aqui el alert no aparce, perdon xD.

Comment: quieres que se quede el focus en el text-area?

Comment: Así es, para que se  pueda validar la condición.